# Skipping prompts when opening excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that loops through a folder of files but the files are all really large so they take a long time to open and they're all set to read-only.
I would like to skip the read-only prompt as well as an update links prompt that comes up. I've tried these pieces of code with no luck

```
(1) ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
 Set Scebook = Workbooks.Open(xPath & xFile)

(2)Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Scebook = Workbooks.Open(xPath & xFile)

(3) Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set Scebook = Workbooks.Open(xPath & xFile)

(4) Application.EnableEvents = False
Set Scebook = Workbooks.Open(xPath & xFile)

(5)Set Scebook = Workbooks.Open(xPath & xFile,_ 
IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the optional read only and update links in the open method:

```
Set Scebook = Workbooks.Open(xPath & xFile,0,1)
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel)

Comment: Thanks, it finally skipped the prompts!